# How to place an icon on the first line and text on the second line?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

The title pretty much explains itself. I have flex container and on the inside I have two divs inside column that are supposed to be on different lines but I can't get them to work like that.

Tags like **br**, **p** won't work for some reason.

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsanw7oL/1/)

**HTML**

```
<ion-content has-header="false">
   <div class="row no-padding">
    <div class="col dashboard-top-item center">
      <div class="ion-ionic"></div>
      <div>Second line</div>
    </div>
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

**CSS**

```
  .dashboard-top-item {
    border-width: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #444444;
    background-color: #595858;
    color: #D0D0D0;
    height: 21vh;
    font-size: medium;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

How could I do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: not working..tried even clear.. :p

Comment: `flex-flow: column` for `.dashboard-top-item` not sure how it will work outside minimal example, tho.

Comment: @Green It worked out.

Comment: add   'display:inline-table;' also working :p

Comment: @Leothelion Not sure what option is better

Comment: Then use whatever you want to  XD

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm myself backend guy and sometimes I find it hard to solve even these little challenges related to CSS.

Comment: If you are using `flex` then try staying within `flex`. If you want to use `inline-table` there... Build it on tables then ;)

Comment: Never hesitate in asking questions..This is the way we learn.. :)

Comment: @Green would you like to create an answer?

Comment: Go green.. answer green :p

Comment: @Green I want you to teach me CSS. You seem like a guy that knows things. :D

Comment: Don't make me blush :P

Comment: @Green No, really. Be my master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `flex-flow`:

Just add into yours `.dashboard-top-item` this CSS property with value:

```
flex-flow: column;
```

Result: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lde4spc2).

## Using `flex-wrap` and `min-width`:

This one is a little bit more complex.

```
.dashboard-top-item {
  border-width: 0px 2px 0px 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #444444;
  background-color: #595858;
  color: #D0D0D0;
  font-size: medium;
  padding: 4vh; /* not fixed height */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow flex to wrap */
}
/* in addition: */
.dashboard-top-item > div {
  flex: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}
.ion-ionic {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Result: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2fjamwf/).